# gcsfuse not enough free space error when trying to add file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcsfuse

I have successfully installed gcsfuse and can mount a bucket and explore its contents. However whenever I try to copy or save a file to the mount I get the error:

> The item “test.txt” can’t be copied because there isn’t enough free space.

A file still appears in the folder but is zero bytes in size, the same is true if I look at the online file browser.

System info:

- OS: *OS X 10.10.5*
- Version: *gcsfuse-0.11.2*
- OSXFUSE: 2.8.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/issues/125) that I've now fixed, and is gone as of gcsfuse v0.12.0. Thanks for the report! You can update with:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

gcsfuse stages file contents in a local temporary directory before writing them to GCS (see documentation [here](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse#downloading-object-contents)).

You'll need to make sure you have enough free space in the temporary directory (which defaults to the target of the `/tmp` symlink on OS X) to cover the size of the file you're trying to write. You can control the location of the temporary directory with the `--temp-dir` flag to gcsfuse.

Comment: I have over 200GB free on the drive, its just a small <1mb file. I also tried moving the temp folder to one in my user folder and the same thing happened.

Comment: Temporarily turn off the Time Machine to see if the issue will go. Use this command:  `sudo tmutil disablelocal`.
You can trun it on later using: `sudo tmutil enablelocal`

Comment: Tried that, still getting the same error.

Comment: What are you using to copy the file? Does it happen with `cp` in the terminal?

Comment: Actually, I've been able to reproduce the issue. See my [other answer](http://serverfault.com/a/720234/302182). Will fix this when I get to work on Monday.